# Why do the elements below also move to the right with this css?

Tags: css

The code below displays some text (`#_EVENTEXCERPT`) and displays a picture (`#_EVENTIMAGE`). I want it so the text is on the left and the image on the right, so they are next to each other, as this code does. Below this there is a `<a href="#_EVENTURL` with lots of css which makes this link into an orange button. Currently, this orange button is being moved right with the image. I don't want this to happen, how can I move the image next to the text (as is currently), but leave the `<a href` to the left?

**from style sheet:**

```
#eventexcandimage {
width: 100%;
}
```

**from .php file:**

```
   <div id="eventexcandimage"> 
            <span style="width: 50%;  float: left; "> #_EVENTEXCERPT </span> 
 #_EVENTIMAGE  </div>
        </li>
            <li>

         <span style="width:50%;  " > <a href="#_EVENTURL"  style=" -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ed834e;
                -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ed834e;
                box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ed834e;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ed834e),   color-stop(1, #ed834e) );
            background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ed834e 5%, #ed834e 100% );
                background-color:#ed834e;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
                 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
                border-top-left-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
                border-top-right-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
                border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
                border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                text-indent:0px;
                display:inline-block;
                color:#fffffb;
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size:13px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-style:normal;
                height:35px;
                line-height:35px;
                width:111px;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-align:center;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ed834e;
            "> More Info /  Book</a>  </span>
```

Thank-you!

**UPDATE:** YI want the button to be on a new line below the text/image. It is currently above the image on the right, I don't know why.

Comment: You should remove that inline css from your `#_EVENTURL` and create a class for it. It won't solve your problem but it'll make reading/writing additional HTML/PHP a lot easier on you.

Comment: @press Thanks, I do usually but css in a separate style sheet. Have you got any ideas how I may solve this please?

Comment: What do you mean you want the button to the left? You mean to be on a new line below the text/image?

Comment: @slime yes , I need to get better at explaining.  The button is currently above the image on the right, where I don't want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I took your code and hopefully made it work the way you wanted it to(?)..Maybe.

Also just below your code I rewrote it not using `span` or `li` but rather `div`'s as they're better for positioning than the former two. Here is link to the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb8zb9fd/1/) as well it attached as a snippet.

```css
.btn {
     -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ed834e;
                -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ed834e;
                box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ed834e;
                background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ed834e),   color-stop(1, #ed834e) );
            background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ed834e 5%, #ed834e 100% );
                background-color:#ed834e;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
                 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
                border-top-left-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
                border-top-right-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
                border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
                -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
                border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
                text-indent:0px;
                display:inline-block;
                color:#fffffb;
                font-family:Arial;
                font-size:13px;
                font-weight:bold;
                font-style:normal;
                height:35px;
                line-height:35px;
                width:111px;
                text-decoration:none;
                text-align:center;
                text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ed834e;
}

.event {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.event_info {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.event-text {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.event-text > h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.event-img {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div id="eventexcandimage">
            <span style="width: 50%;  float: left; ">
                #_EVENTEXCERPT
            </span> 
            <div style="width: 50%; float: left;">
                <img  class="img" src="" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li style="clear: both;"> <span style="width:50%;  "> <a href="#_EVENTURL" class="btn"> More Info /  Book</a>  </span> 
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="event">
    <div class="event-info">
        <div class="event-text">
            <h3>Event Title</h3>
            <p>Text about your event</p>
        </div>
        <div class="event-img">
            <img class="img" src="" />
        </div>
    </div> <!-- End event-info -->
    <div style="clear: both;">
        <a href="#" class="btn">More Info / Book</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that your provided HTML has been cut off because some of your tags are not properly opened nor closed, but that's irrelevant as to why you're seeing the behavior you are.

`span` by default is displayed inline (everything naturally flowing on a line). You have your button in a span which means it's trying to stay on the same line as the things before it, which is doing what you're seeing. So what can you do? Well, the quickest fix is to make this button start on a new line. Change the display on the button to `display:block`. Block level elements take up the entire width, which will force a line break since something that is full width can't share the line with other things.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced `display:inline-block;` with `display:block;` but it didn't change anything (I cleared my cache).

Comment: @Leonagrey Instead of adding `display:block` to the `a` tag, add it to the `span` tag that is holding it.